# How can i connect my 4 objects in my jsp file so it can run perfectly

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

So i have been working on this project my teacher gave me. A SIMPLE(but problematic for me) Java website made from 4 objects, 1 servlet, and 1 jsp file. And after long hours of finding the error, i still can't find it. look for the error below:
[image]

here is my code for the servlet:

```
package control;

import jakarta.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

import objects.Address;
import objects.Family;
import objects.Program;
import objects.Student;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ControllerKo
 */
public class ControllerKo extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ControllerKo() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        request.setAttribute("pogi", "Institute of Technology");
        
        Student js = new Student();
        js.setName("Martin Parma");
        js.setAge("19 years old");
        js.setcivilStatus("Single");
        js.setGender("Male");
        js.setcontactNumber("09513300384");
        
        Program add = new Program();
        add.setdegree("Diploma in COmputer Engineering");
        add.setregIreg("Regular");
        add.setSem("2nd Sem");
        add.setyearLevel("2nd Year");
        
        Address in = new Address();
        in.setCity("Caloocan City");
        in.setBrgy("176");
        in.setBlkNumber("Block 28 Lot Excess");
        in.setRegion("NCR");
        in.setPostalCode("1428");
        
        Family me = new Family();
        me.setfatherName("Renee");
        me.setmotherName("Thelma");
        me.setSiblings("one");
        me.setfamilySize("4");
        
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

the jsp file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <%@ page import="objects.Student"%>     
 <%@ page import="objects.Address"%>  
 <%@ page import="objects.Program"%>  
 <%@ page import="objects.Family"%>      
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1> Testing by DCPET 2-2</h1>
 <h2> Welcome to Web Systems </h2>
 <h3><%=request.getAttribute("pogi")%></h3>
 
 <%
 
 Student js = new Student();
 js = (Student)request.getAttribute("student");
 
 Address in = new Address();
 in = (Address)request.getAttribute("address");
 
 Program add = new Program();
 add = (Program)request.getAttribute("program");
 
 Family me = new Family();
 me = (Family)request.getAttribute("family");
 
 
 %>
 
 
 <table border="1">
 
 
<tr>
 <td>First Name
 </td>
 <td>
 <%=js.getName()%>

 </tr>
 
 
 </table>

 
</body>
</html>
```

and my 4 objects:

```
package objects;

public class Student {
    
    String Fname;
    String age;
    String civilStatus;
    String gender;
    String contactNumber;
    
    public String getName() {
        return Fname;
    }
    public void setName(String Fname) {
        this.Fname = Fname;
    }
    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getcivilStatus() {
        return civilStatus;
    }
    public void setcivilStatus(String civilStatus) {
        this.civilStatus = civilStatus;
    }
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public String getcontactNumber() {
        return contactNumber;
    }
    public void setcontactNumber(String contactNumber) {
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
    }
    
}
```

---

```
package objects;

public class Program {

    String degree;
    String yearLevel;
    String Sem;
    String regIreg;
    
    public String getdegree() {
        return degree;
    }
    public void setdegree(String degree) {
        this.degree = degree;
    }
    public String getyearLevel() {
        return yearLevel;
    }
    public void setyearLevel(String yearLevel) {
        this.yearLevel = yearLevel;
    }
    public String getSem() {
        return Sem;
    }
    public void setSem(String Sem) {
        this.Sem = Sem;
    }
    public String getregIreg() {
        return regIreg;
    }
    public void setregIreg(String regIreg) {
        this.regIreg = regIreg;
    }
    
    
}
```

---

```
package objects;

public class Address {

    String region;
    String city;
    String brgy;
    String blkNumber;
    String unitNumber;
    String postalCode;
   
    public String getRegion() {
        return region;
    }
    public void setRegion(String region) {
        this.region = region;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getBrgy() {
        return brgy;
    }
    public void setBrgy(String brgy) {
        this.brgy = brgy;
    }
    public String getBlkNumber() {
        return blkNumber;
    }
    public void setBlkNumber(String blkNumber) {
        this.blkNumber = blkNumber;
    }
    public String getUnitNumber() {
        return unitNumber;
    }
    public void setUnitNumber(String unitNumber) {
        this.unitNumber = unitNumber;
    }
    public String getPostalCode() {
        return postalCode;
    }
    public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
    }
    
}
```

---

```
package objects;

public class Family {
    
    String fatherName;
    String motherName;
    String siblings;
    String familySize;
    
    public String getfatherName() {
        return fatherName;
    }
    public void setfatherName(String fatherName) {
        this.fatherName = fatherName;
    }
    public String getmotherName() {
        return motherName;
    }
    public void setmotherName(String motherName) {
        this.motherName = motherName;
    }
    public String getSiblings() {
        return siblings;
    }
    public void setSiblings(String siblings) {
        this.siblings = siblings;
    }
    public String getfamilySize() {
        return familySize;
    }
    public void setfamilySize(String familySize) {
        this.familySize = familySize;
    }
}
```

it seems that the objects can't connect to my jsp file so it can't run <%=js.getName()%>. So what can i do? Sorry i am a beginner to this kind of school stuff.

Comment: You need to save your object(s) as [attributes of the `Request`](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/servlets/how-put-object-request-httpservletrequest-servlet/). Also you need to [work on your naming - your beans are wrong](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions)

Comment: "So what can i do?" - First, stop using scriptlets in your code.